# Why is delay with VcXsrv so much slower than Xming when X11 forwarding

Tags: x11-forwarding, x-server, xming, vcxsrv

I was beating my head against the wall trying to figure out why opening an application through X11 forwarding was taking so long.  To open the simplest app like xclock was taking ~20 seconds for the GUI to appear.  This was with VcXsrv.

After exhausting ideas on the Linux client, I tried installing Xming on my Windows 10 machine instead and immediately xclock started opening almost instantly (as one would expect).

Could anybody with more experience using these tools suggest why this could be?  Or should I just accept that VcXsrv is a POS?

Comment: Could you try an even simpler app, such as `xdpyinfo`?

Comment: This started happening to me after Windows 10 2004, I don't think VcXsrv is the problem.

Comment: Is it possible that the one triggers a reverse lookup for some reason and you don't have DNS entries?

Comment: Reached this question when searching for why WSL windowed apps would take long when using VcXsrv for display. VcXsrv version 1.20.14 on Windows 11 (10.0.22000.1817). On some systems, it opens in no time. And on others, one has to wait for minutes. Confirming that Windows Defender allows app vcxsrv.exe (from the right path) on Domain, Private and Public.

In context of DNS entries (and WSL), will like to have more details of what you have in mind @Marius. Does the Windows host need to resolve FQDNs for VcXsrv clients? Or the client Linux needs to resolve VcXsrv host FQDN ?